# SELECT element option values

Tags: html

i am doing a `select` in html then I have something in the JS part like this

```
var languageEN = "en,1";
var languageFR = "fr,2";
var languageDE = "de,3";
```

and my html markup will be like

```
<select style="display: none;" id="select">
  <option value=languageEN>English</option>
  <option value=languageFR>Francais</option>
  <option value=languageDE>Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

but it seems that I am hitting undefined.

I been trying to find whats the correct syntax to include in the `option value` but no avail. thanks.

Comment: and these are supposed to fit together how and do what?

Comment: i am just trying to pass a string value of "en,1" a shorthand of the language and a number to the backend for query purposes..

Comment: JavaScript does not automatically communicate with the HTML/DOM and do things like template style variable interpolation (which it sounds like you were expecting).  You'd need to write for this kind of thing, and for this use case it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: so you can just put `value=1` na?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off translating the "languageXX" strings in the resulting page's server-side script? It's really hard to understand what you're trying to gain by doing it client-side other than a hassle if they turn JS off or happen to change the values of your variables.

Comment: @IC, the variables are only for my use

Comment: @MattWhippie yea I could just hard code the value into the option value and it will save me a lot of trouble but i fear that if i go and someone new takes over then it will be hard for them to find this.

Answer (score 2):

If using PHP is an option you could do this. The first part could go at the top of the page, then the second part wherever the select needed to be. You could add as many options or change them any way you liked this way.

```
<?php
    $options = array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'English',
            'value' => 'languageEN'
        ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'Francais',
            'value' => 'languageFR'
        ),
        2 => array(
            'name' => 'Deutsch',
            'value' => 'languageDE'
        ),
    );?>

<select style="display: none;" id="select">
<?php
    foreach ($options as $option);
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$option['value'].'">".$option['name'].'</option>'
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry this isn't what I am looking for, I just want to ask whether its possible to pass in variables to a select element in html so that when there is a need to switch the values, its easier, this is might as well hardcoding the value "en,1" into the option value.

Comment: I just reread your question and still didn't get what you just said from it. You may want to edit it with what you just wrote. What you want is easy with PHP, is that an option?

Comment: thumbs up for the suggestion, but PHP is not an option :D thanks

Comment: =( damn. Well my jQuery and js suck so I'll leave this to someone else then, good luck.